# Algorithm to find primes $q$ and $p$ with $q\, |\, p - 1$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I understand that if $p$ is prime then $p-1$ must be composite (at least divisible by $2$ as it is even). But how does an algorithm find a prime $q$ such that $q \cdot r = p - 1$. I thought prime factorisation is such a hard problem?

Comment: what are the restrictions on $q$? $q=2$ is always a solution

Comment: @qwr You are obviously right. $q$ is supposed to be a great prime. The common reccomendation for crypto algorithms seems to be that the bit-width of $p$ is about 3 or 4 times the bit-width of $q$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The critical facts enabling to find such $p$ in practice are:

- We can easily tell with practical certainty if an integer with many thousand bits is prime or not, using a primality test such as [Miller-Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_and_Solovay%E2%80%93Strassen_primality_test), even though we are typically unable to tell all its factors when it is not prime.
- About $1.4/b$ integers of $b$ bits are prime. Thus it is more likely than not that randomly trying $b$ integers of $b$ bits will uncover a prime (for $b>4$).

Hence a possible method to find a somewhat random large prime $p$ with some large known random prime $q$ dividing $p-1$ is:

- first randomly select a suitably large prime $q$
- for successive $r$ of suitable size

  - compute $p\gets q\,r+1$
  - if $p$ is prime

    - output $p$ and stop.

There are refinements to this. Obviously, we can restrict to even $r$. That's a special case with $s=2$ of a more general tweak: for any small prime $s$, it must hold that $q\,r+1\bmod s\ne0$, thus $r\bmod s\ne-q^{-1}\bmod s$. This allows to build a sieve of possible $r$, eliminating most candidates without a full primality test.

There are standardized algorithms to generate such $p$ and $q$, including deterministically from a seed. See [FIPS 186-4 appendix A.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=40)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply! This answers all my questions. :-)